# main function doesn't quit after return 0, shmctl doesn't delete segment

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm trying to use shared memory as pipe and I encounter several problems:

1. I can't manage to delete the segment
2. The main function doesn't exit, after `return 0`

   ```
   int main()
   {
     int spd[2], pid, rb;
     char buff[4096];
     if (shm_pipe_pipe(spd) < 0)
     {
           perror("shm_pipe_pipe");
           exit(1);
     }
     if (fork())
     {
           rb = shm_pipe_read(spd[0], buff, sizeof(buff));
           if (rb > 0)
                   write(1, buff, rb);
     }
     else
     {
            shm_pipe_write(spd[1], "hello world!\n", sizeof("hello world!\n"));
     }

     shm_pipe_close(spd[0]);
     shm_pipe_close(spd[1]);
     printf("end main\n");
     return 0;
   }
   ```

the last output is "end main", but the program doesn't close and return to bash...
I positive it is related to the whole shared memory thing:

`shm_pipe_pipe()` allocates shared memory segment and pointer to shared memory:

```
shmid = shmget(key, PIPE_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0600);
buffer = (char*)shmat(pipes_array[i].m_shmid, NULL, 0)) == NULL)
```

`shm_pipe_write` `and shm_pipe_read` just do memcpy() to/from the shared memory

`shm_pipe_close()` free's the pointer to the segment and deletes the segment:

```
shmdt(buffer);
shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
```

I don't understand why doesn't it work.

It's written in the man page of shmdt that After a `fork(2) the child inherits the attached  shared  memory segments.`

So I tried to use `shmdt` twice, on the father and on the child, but then I get an error

```
Invalid argument
```

when the `main()` stucks after printing "end main" I try to see the status of shared memory with `ipcs -m`, I see that `nattch` is 1, and the `key` is 0...
Only after I `ctrl+c` `main()`, the memory segment is deleted from `ipcs -m`

I'm not sure what further information I should bring. I didn't write all the functions cause that's a lot and I don't think it's matter...

Comment: What does the implementation of `shm_pipe_pipe()` do?  Whose implementation is it?  Does it register a callback with `atexit()`?  If so, is the program stuck in the callback function, waiting for some condition to be realized?  You could improve the debugging by adding print statements liberally (before the `shm_pipe_read()`, after it, before the `shm_pipe_write()`, after it) and tagging the outputs with the process ID, and so on.  But without knowing what's in those `shm_pipe_*()` functions, no-one can really help you. Also, how are you controlling access to the shared memory?  Semaphores?

Comment: Hard to help without the code of `shm_pipe*()`. My guess on the pipe read that blocks expecting [more] input. Thus the child doesn't die and you have only one *end main* displayed.

Comment: I use prints to see what's going on in there, Everything looks fine.. In the added code I didn't write them, just the "end main" print...

I implement the **shm_pipe_pipe()** and the other functions, I didn't add them cause they have more unrelated things to the question, I can add them..
I will first try something with what @ring0 told and then post more...
thanks

Comment: If this is C only, please don't cast `void *` to `char *`, it hurts.

Comment: Have you ever tried using one of those wonderful things called debuggers?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are confused about something.

> the last output is "end main"
>
> shm_pipe_close() free's the pointer to the segment and deletes the segment

Yet as written -- with no `exit` in the child block -- this code *should* run **in both parent and child**:

```
  shm_pipe_close(spd[0]);
  shm_pipe_close(spd[1]);
  printf("end main\n");
```

In other words, twice (unless the child is stalled in `shm_pipe_read`, see below). Which is probably unintentional, if "deleting the segment" refers to a singular shared mem entity.

Beyond that, your outcome depends on whether or not `shm_pipe_read` and `shm_pipe_write` work like normal blocking read/write calls on a pipe, which wait until the data is read or written at the other end.  I'm guessing your write is certainly *not* that way and likely neither is the read.

That would mean that `shm_pipe_write` could happen in the parent, then the "pipe" (which is really a shared mem segment) is immediately deleted.  If this causes something in `shm_pipe_read` to stall (because the segment is gone), it might (as ring0 says in a comment) explain your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is right here:

```
 shmid = shmget(key, PIPE_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0600);
```

Change the permissions so both child and parent can access the shared memory segment:

```
 shmid = shmget(key, PIPE_SIZE, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666);
```

---

Since I don't know exactly what your functions are doing... here's a similar program that works and you can reference to see if you have other mistakes (BTW - I changed the permissions in here to 0600 and I could see the main process complete but the child hang):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    key_t key = 1111;
    int shmid;
    char *buff;
    char *s;
    char *addr = NULL;

    if((shmid = shmget(key, 4096, IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666)) < 0 ) {
         perror("shmget");
        return -1;
    }
    if((buff = shmat(shmid, addr, 0)) == (char *)-1) {
        perror("shmat");
        return -1;
    }
    if(fork()){
      printf("I'm the child\n");
      while(strlen(buff) == 0) {}
      for(s = buff; *s != NULL; s++)
        putchar(*s);
      printf("\nChild is done\n");
    }
    else {
      printf("I'm the parent\n");
       strcpy(buff, "hello world!\0");
      printf("Parent is done.\n");
    }
    shmdt(addr);
    shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Permission bits of `0600` grant read and write access to the Unix user that created the segment. Unless the child changes its effective UID before it tries to attach the shared memory segment (obviously not the case here), this is not a permission problem. Your sample program functions correctly with `0600` (and you've got the parent/child parts swapped).